# Finding a specific text in a cell then deleting its row

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

Okay, so I have a name list where I write names in. Those names go in alphabetical order in another list where I give the names numbers. But whenever I add or remove names, cell shift places but the numbers remain the same, so if Adam had 1 1 1 1 and Bobby 2 2 2 2, by adding Ben he will take Bobby's place (because of the alphabetical order) and have 2 2 2 2 while Bobby will have 0 0 0 0. How do I make the numbers go after the name?
Photos with the examples (watch where appleboy comes in):

[image: 1]

The sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rH-4wzAzgOZ31jfH8MPkFnLCLzET3tfiGQrxaUpIg6Y/edit#gid=2041472100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have a lot of options...

you can either have your names in order as you add them, then assign numbers to them (both actions on the same sheet) and then use simple `SORT` formula in sheet2 to get alphabetically sorted those names.

```
=SORT(sheet1!A2:F)
```

---

the 2nd option is to set up a lookup table on some helper sheet3 and then use `ArrayFormula` with `VLOOKUP` to match the ID (unique names). and then in B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, sheet3!A:F, {2,3,4,5,6}, 0)))
```

---

the 3rd option would be to use a sorting script for a specified range

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("ChangeSheetNameHere");
var range = sheet.getRange("A2:Z");

function onEdit(e)  {
  range.sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time